# Actualización de stock en base FireBase con react js

Tags: reactjs, base-de-datos, firebase, actualizacion

ando con problemas para hacer una actualización de stock cuando finalizo el pedido de mi carrito de compras.
Tengo los datos, ya que los puedo mostrar como componentes y en mi carrito de compras, o sea que veo mi stock actual y veo la cantidad a comprar, pero me faltaría como hace una función, para que luego de confirmar la compra, se actualice el stock en firebase
Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Aca esta el pastebin

https://pastebin.com/Q7aZ5SV9

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y agrega el código de lo que has intentado